# Use mutableStateOf and Flow together, but cannot change UI component state

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a variable in the ViewModel, it's a boolean called *isRefreshing*. In the UI component, when I click the button, onClick will call the function *refreshList* in viewmodel and changes the value of *isRefreshing*. At the beginning of *refreshList*, *isrefreshing* will be set to true and at the end of the function *isrefreshing* will be set to false. When *isRefreshing* is true, the component will be CircularProgressIndicator. However, when I click the button, the component changes to CircularProgressIndicator but never change back to original component.
***The detailed code is as follows.***

In my ViewModel, I have a flag variable like below:

```
var isRefreshing by mutableStateOf(false)
    private set
```

The component uses *isRefreshing* like below:

```
if (songVM.isRefreshing) {
    CircularProgressIndicator(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary)
} else {
    Image(
        imageVector = Icons.Default.Refresh,
        contentDescription = null,
    )
}
```

The ViewModel have another function and the value of *isRefreshing* only changes in this function:

```
suspend fun refreshList() {
        isRefreshing = true

        // Other Codes

        getAllBySelectOrder(0)
        isRefreshing = false
    }
```

getAllBySelectOrder() is defined as below:

```
private suspend fun getAllBySelectOrder(type: Int) {
        val flow = when (type) {
            0 -> songsRepository.getAllOrderById()
            1 -> songsRepository.getAllOrderBySinger()
            else -> songsRepository.getAllOrderBySong()
        }
        combine(flow) { flowArr ->
            SongsViewState(flowArr[0])
        }.collect { _songsState.value = it }
}
```

Some other relevant codes:

```
private val _songsState = MutableStateFlow(SongsViewState())
data class SongsViewState(
    val songs: List<SongBean> = emptyList()
)
```

I test the code and found the keypoint is *getAllBySelectOrder()*. If I delete this function, everything will work correctly but when I add this function, it cannot work. I asked the GPT and it's said the problem is caused by *collect*. I  don't know how to fix it. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might get a better response if you frame this as a coroutine issue. The fact that the UI is not updating is because `isRefreshing` is always `true` because  `getAllBySelectOrder()` never returns. It never returns because the flow collected by `getAllBySelectOrder()` is never closed. You don't provide enough information to determine why this. Factoring out Compose would make why more clear and keep the question short.

Comment: Is `isRefreshing` used only to indicate whether SongsViewState is currently loading?

Comment: @Tenfour04 yes, the value of isRefreshing changed only in refreshList()

Answer (score 0):

Most Flows are infinite, which means if you call `collect()` on them, the function that calls `collect()` will never return. It just hangs on where it calls `collect()`.

The Flows from your repository I am assuming are infinite and monitor a database indefinitely, so they emit a new item each time something from the database is changed. So what you need to do is to turn off `isRefreshing` on the first item and then allow the flow to continue to be collected.

Also, I don't think you should make `refreshList()` a suspend function. That's really inconvenient to call from the UI side, and it's unnecessary since Compose behaves reactively--there's no need for the caller to wait for it to finish.

So, putting this together, we change `refreshList()` to be non-suspending. `getAllBySelectOrder` is changed so it starts a coroutine and turns off `isLoading` when something is collected. It should be fine for it to simply turn it off for every item collected. The other thing you need to do is cancel any previous flow colelction in this function so you aren't collecting obsolete flows when `getAllBySelectOrder()` has been called with a different parameter.

```
fun refreshList() {
    isRefreshing = true

        // Other Codes

    getAllBySelectOrder(0)
}

private var getAllBySelectOrderJob: Job? = null

private fun getAllBySelectOrder(type: Int) {
    getAllBySelectOrderJob?.cancel()
    getAllBySelectOrderJob = viewModelScope.launch {
        when (type) {
            0 -> songsRepository.getAllOrderById()
            1 -> songsRepository.getAllOrderBySinger()
            else -> songsRepository.getAllOrderBySong()
        }.collect { 
            _songsState.value = SongsViewState(it)
            isRefreshing = false
        }
    }
}

// Or, if you're familiar with launchIn, I think this is easier to read:

private fun getAllBySelectOrder(type: Int) {
    val flow = when (type) {
            0 -> songsRepository.getAllOrderById()
            1 -> songsRepository.getAllOrderBySinger()
            else -> songsRepository.getAllOrderBySong()
        }.onEach { 
            _songsState.value = SongsViewState(it)
            isRefreshing = false
        }

    getAllBySelectOrderJob?.cancel()
    getAllBySelectOrderJob = flow.launchIn(viewModelScope)
}
```